# SQL Convert Date Format from varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a `varchar` column in a table that contains data that looks like this:

```
2010-06-24-00.00.00.000000
```

I need to convert it to a `Date` that looks like this:

```
6/24/2010
```

Using T-SQL. How can I do this? I'm using SQL Server 2012.

What date format is this? `2010-06-24-00.00.00.000000`

Comment: Which RDBMS/version are you using?  SQL Server, MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the FORMAT function:

```
FORMAT(datefield,'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

But, since it's a VARCHAR, to use the FORMAT function you have to first CAST the date portion as a date:

```
FORMAT(CAST(LEFT(stringdatefield,10) AS DATE),'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know about the `FORMAT`function. Guess it's time to install 2012 and leave 2008 behind :)
+1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
select convert(date, left('2010-06-24-00.00.00.000000', 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a optional parameter to the convert function.  If you want the result to be a string, simply do this:

```
CONVERT(varchar(8),datefield,1)
```

If you want the result to be a DATE type, cast it:

```
CAST(CONVERT(varchar(8),datefield,1) as DATE)
```